# Complete intersection composed with a $N$-tuple embedding.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $i:X \to \mathbb{P}^n_k$ be an smooth projective curve which is a complete intersection in $\mathbb{P}^n_k$ with $g\geq 2$. Let $f: \mathbb{P}^n_k \to \mathbb{P}^m_k$ be the closed immersion associated to the canonical surjection of a twisting sheaf of positive degree. Let $f \circ i$ the resulting closed immersion.

It is true that this curve sitting inside $\mathbb{P}^m_k$ is still a complete intersection in the new projective space? If the answer is negative I would be interested in knowing by how many homogeneous (or a bound) polynomials it will be generated.

Comment: This is false in general. Take a quartic curve $X$ in the plane (so genus is 3) and consider $N=2$. Then, we get a degree 8 curve in $\mathbb{P}^5$. If it were a complete intersection, then $K_X=\mathcal{O}_X(r)$ for some integer $r$. Then $4=2g-2=\deg K_X=8r$, impossible.